# Monitor your Wi-Fi connection not found on High Sierra

Tags: wifi, high-sierra

Your Mac can monitor your Wi-Fi connection for intermittent issues, such as dropped connections.

Well I know that and used it before, but can not find it on High Sierra.

The output looked like this

[image: monitor]

If Wireless Diagnostics finds an issue, it stops monitoring and shows a brief description of the issue.

[image: Dropped]

**So where is this wonderful tool on High Sierra.**

Just to make it clear..I am not looking for this 160MB WirelessDiagnostics_C02W92Z5J1WL_...tar report. It is loaded with files no normal human can understand.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it can be found in `/System/Library/CoreServices/`, but I'm not sure what it will be named in High Sierra, maybe `Network Diagnostics.app`

Comment: ok looking for it

Comment: @Buscar웃 did you find it?

Comment: sorry, did not , the one I am looking for is not there

Comment: ok, are you looking for `Network Diagnostics.app`, or just a way to monitor your Wi-Fi connection?

Comment: It is not the network diagnostics, take another look into my question. I was very explicit what I am looking for.

Comment: hmmmm, I'm not sure if you can monitor your Wi-Fi connection using an apple app in High Sierra like that, though you probably can using Little Snitch (https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html)

Comment: It looks like Apple dropped it since Sierra, what a shame